# Using the seed value from rake in unit and functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rake-test

When running unit and functional tests using rake, on a rails application, I notice that there is a seed value which is specified on the command line: **--seed x**

```
$ rake test
(in /code/blah)
Loaded suite /../ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.
Finished in 0.12345 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

Test run options: --seed 20290
```

I assume it is possible to use this value in the tests, but I can't figure out how.
I've tried Google, Rails Guides et al. but can't seem to find the answer.

EDIT:

Could this seed value be the option that is used by Minitest to randomize the execution order of tests?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

I found this online about MiniTest: http://www.mikeperham.com/2012/09/25/minitest-ruby-1-9s-test-framework/

Turns out, you are right. It is about randomizing the execution order of tests. You can explicitly use them like this:

```
rake TESTOPTS="--seed=1261"
```

(according to the above link).

Comment: This does not work... Use the answer below for minitest

Comment: Oh, it affects only the order of running tests... On a side note, haven't you ever run into problems with `rake TESTOPTS=...`? I just [did](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/bc33a8bb81d1b0502a157349427c56f3).

Answer (score 81):

The answer from [MrDanA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6441173/665240) is correct. This solution also works and is slightly shorter and easier to remember.

```
SEED=20290 rake test
```

Comment: or alternatively `rake test SEED=20290`